# Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class ImageView Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException only on rooted devices

Tags: android, android-layout, png, rooted-device

First of all, I looked at all the SO posts with a similar subject and none of them cover my particular issue. What's different is that the ImageView resource in question is a .png, not a vector drawable, and the problem occurs only on rooted devices (four different ones, in my case). Some are running Android 5.1 and one, 7.1.2. The image that's failing is icon.png, which exists in drawable and all the other drawable-* folders.

Here is the crash log:

> android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName (ResourcesImpl.java:228)
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie (ResourcesImpl.java:687)
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable (ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:858)
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:928)
>   android.widget.ImageView. (ImageView.java:162)
>   android.widget.ImageView. (ImageView.java:150)
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView. (AppCompatImageView.java:72)
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView. (AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:769)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:727)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:858)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:861)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:426)
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:377)
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
>   uomini.com.wegrok.LaunchActivity.onCreate (LaunchActivity.java:325)
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6682)
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1118)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2619)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2727)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1478)
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6121)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:889)
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:779)

The layout file is the following:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/version"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="@string/copyright"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: Do you have `icon.png` in default `drawable` folder also ?

Comment: Yes. And note that the problem only has occurred on rooted devices.